# For Stock Market integration with Salesforce, What is the Best way to get real time data per second, without hitting API limits

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-marketing-cloud

Third party system has Real Time data change. How do we suggest them to integrate with Salesforce to sync data?

Like CDC, Platform Events, Streaming API or any other middleware systems like mulesoft or Heroku to be used ?

Looking for a design to this use case.